# How can we find the shortest paths in the boundaries of a matrix?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

This is another version of a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3715230/how-can-we-find-the-shortest-distances-in-an-irregular-shape).

In this image,

[image]

we have all the points within the shape (yellow area), which can be represented as a matrix.

We aim to connect the boundary points (black dots) within the shape.

**How can we find the closest boundary point to each boundary point while we can draw a circle inside the shape (yellow area) by the resulting line as the diameter?**

The basic solution is to check all points for any given point. The key is to reduce the number of calculations, as I wish to scale up this approach for large and complicated systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the circle with diameter $BA$ is supposed to be within the region bounded by your curve, and that curve has tangent lines at $B$ and $A$, then those tangent lines must be perpendicular to $BA$.  So given $B$, 
take a line perpendicular to the tangent line to the curve at $B$, and see where it first intersects the curve.  That point must be $A$.  But if $BA$ is not perpendicular to the tangent line to the curve at $A$, then there is no solution.

Of course it is still not guaranteed that the circle will be within the region, but if there is a solution it must be this one.

Comment: The tangent approach is subtle. It can lead me somewhere if it is not the ultimate solution. I will work on it.